# I'm getting the default execution timeout even though I've set everything to zero

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've got a stored procedure that's timing out despite the fact that I've set both the server's execution-timeout and the connection's execution-timeout to zero, which should make it unlimited.

It times out at exactly 10 minutes, which is the default timeout, so it would seem to be still getting that from *somewhere*.

Any ideas?

Note that this stored procedure used to run for hours w/o timing out, but recently I've made some changes to it, such as using a cursor for the iteration, using a temporary table and using some explicit transactions -- maybe that has something to do with the problem.

Comment: You should set up a timeout on your application layer (Java/C#)? Are you calling SP from SSMS?

Comment: Are you using linked servers/remote queries? The default timeout for that is indeed 10 minutes (which is a [server-wide option](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option)); I'm not aware of any other timeouts applied by SQL Server or SSMS by default (and queries will run forever until cancelled).

Comment: I am in fact running the sproc from SSMS.  I have set the server-wide timeout to zero, and my connection, too, has the timeout set to zero.

Comment: Any chance you're getting some sort of double-hop issue where you do a remote query to a server, which in turn is doing some remoting? Seems improbable but this is the stage of eliminating the impossible so you can get at the truth. For a basic test, you could see if a (really boring) `WAITFOR DELAY '00:11:00'`, when done remotely, gives a timeout. If so you know the setting isn't being applied properly, if not then at least that's not the issue. Also, I know remote connections are actually subject to pooling, so worst case a server restart is still necessary even though the docs say it's not.

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert, but the solution ended up being simpler than that.  I appreciate the effort and the information.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!  It seems there’s a *third* (and possibly even a fourth) place where the timeout can be set – under Options -> Query Execution (the possible fourth is in the Query window’s context menu Query Options).